# "When converting a string to DateTime" Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

```
OdbcConnection connPulse = new OdbcConnection();
connPulse.ConnectionString = "dsn=TEST;uid=USER;pwd=PASSWORD;"
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1", connPulse);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

I am getting the error:

> "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the
>   date before putting each variable into the DateTime object"

Is this exception to do with the data stored in 'Table1' I have 'Date' data types stored in there, if that is the problem how do I solve this?

Comment: doesn't seem to be an error here.

Comment: Which line exactly ? What is the value of date we talking about?

Comment: On the "da.fill(ds);" line.

Comment: Where do you see the error? Is it when you compile or run the app?

Comment: When I run the app.
Have about 8 different 'DateTime' columns in Table1. All in the format dd/mm/yyyy including many NULLS....